# When proving that a stochastic process is a martingale, why is its integrability (almost always) assumed?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

In a book I'm reading (but I get the impression that many others proceed similarly), when proving that a stochastic process is a martingale, the author proceeds as if integrability is trivial, or somehow given, and simply focus on proving the part of the definition involving the conditional expectation.

For example: Let $M_t = B_t^2-t$, where $B_t$ is a Brownian motion. He simply focus on proving that $E(M_t\mid \mathcal{F_s})=M_s$ for $s<t$.
How does the author know that $E(|B_t^2-t| )<\infty$?

Is there a theorem/property that makes it easy to ensure that the processes are integrable?

Comment: $M_t$ is integrable because $B_t$ is normally distributed, and so has moments of all orders.  But you are right that it should be commented on — it isn't being assumed but rather taken for granted.

Comment: @JohnDawkins Thanks. I had forgotten about the fact the Normal distribution having moments of all orders.